# Get URL of specific link in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a file that contains a bunch of links:

```
<a href="http://site1.com">site 1</a>
<a href="http://site2.com">site 2</a>
<a href="http://site3.com">site 3</a>
```

I want to get the URL to a link with specific text.  For example, search for "site 2" and get back "http://site2.com"

I tried this:

```
preg_match("/.*?[Hh][Rr][Ee][Ff]=\"(.*?)\">site 2<\/[Aa]>.*/", $contents, $match)
```

(I know the HREF= will be the last part of the anchor)

But it returns

```
http://site1.com">site 1</a><a href="http://site2.com
```

Is there a way to do a search backwards, or something?  I know I can do preg_match_all and loop over everything, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Is that file, a HTML file? If so, you can traverse the file easily as a `DOMDocument`.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it's in no way a well-formatted or complete HTML document.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a well-formatted complete HTML document. A DOM parser still might be the right tool for this job. A regex is probably also fine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match("(<a.*?href=[\"']([^\"']+)[\"'][^>]?>site 2</a>)i",$contents,$match);
$result = $match[1];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't think of checking to make sure it didn't include the characters I didn't want... I trimmed it down a bit based off assumptions I'm able to make about my data:

Comment: preg_match("/.*?href=\"([^>]+)\">site 2<\/a>.*/i", $contents, $match)

Comment: @Erik W: Although a plain `>` is not allowed in a URL, it actually is allowed in a quoted attribute value. In that case you should use the delimiting quotation mark in the negated character class.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try using [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/).